# Natural Injection From k-th Exterior Power of the Dual to the Dual of the k-th Exterior Power

Tags: tensor-products, exterior-algebra, dual-spaces

In finite dimensions, we know that $\Lambda^k(V^\star) \cong (\Lambda^k(V))^\star$ by the isomorphism $f^1 \wedge \dots f^k \mapsto \left ( (v_1 \wedge \dots v_k) \mapsto \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} sgn(\sigma) \Pi_{i=1}^k f^i(v_{\sigma(i)}) \right)$. How can we show that this mapping is injective in the general case of $V$ being infinite dimensional? Is it even injective?